# I have problem logged out using flutter firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm trying to log out after login in using my phone number I can log in but when I press logout this error appears:  Notifying id token listeners about a sign-out event. D/FirebaseAuth(31596): Notifying auth state listeners about a sign-out event. and it is not logout

here is my code
`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/container.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class text extends StatefulWidget {
  const text({super.key});

  @override
  State<text> createState() => _textState();
}

class _textState extends State<text> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text('Signed In as'),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Text(user.phoneNumber!),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
              ),
              onPressed: () => {
                FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
              },
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.arrow_back,
                size: 32,
              ),
              label: Text(
                'Sign Out',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`
in the user.phonenumber it prints phone number I logged in with and its correct

Answer (score 0):

The `signOut` method in FirebaseAuth is asynchronous. Making your `onPressed` method asynchronous should solve it.

```
ElevatedButton.icon(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
         ),
         onPressed: () => async {
          FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
         },
         icon: Icon(
           Icons.arrow_back,
           size: 32,
         ),
         label: Text(
          'Sign Out',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
         ),
   ),
```

You should redirect the user to a login page after the signout as well.